# How to define a lambda function that filters list based on subtype of a sum type?

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, custom-data-type, haskell-prelude

The example is taken from a "Haskell programming from first principles"
The goal of filter function is get rid of all the objects except those of 'DbDate' type.

On somone's github I found a way to filter sum types with list comprehension and pattern matching(1). Now I am trying to find a way to redefine this filter with a lambda function(2) or normal "case of" of "if then" function. I do not know how to properly check the type of arguments of a function when I deal with custom data type.

Book doesn't introduce the reader to any super specific library functions, just standard maps, folds, filters and other stuff you'd find in prelude.

```
import Data.Time

data DatabaseItem = DbString String
                  | DbNumber Integer
                  | DbDate   UTCTime
                  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

--List that needs to be filtered
theDatabase :: [DatabaseItem]
theDatabase =
  [ DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1911 5 1)
                    (secondsToDiffTime 34123))
  , DbNumber 9001
  , DbString "Hello, world!"
  , DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1921 5 1)
                    (secondsToDiffTime 34123))
  ]



--1 works fine, found on someone's git hub
filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate dbes = [x | (DbDate x) <- dbes]

--2 Looking for the eqivalents with lambda or "case" or "if then"
--pattern is not satisfactory

filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate dbes = filter (\(DbDate x) -> True) theDatabase
```

Comment: You'll probably think this slightly pedantic, but you're not filtering based on type - all lists in Haskell consist of elements of only one type. You want to filter based on the *constructor* of the element.

Comment: That list comprehension basically works like `temp <- dbes, x <- case temp of { DbDate val -> [val]; _ -> [] }`

Answer (score 6):

`filter` has the type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` so it is not able to change the type of your list.

According to [The Haskell 98 Report (section 3.11)](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html) the list comprehension used in the code you found on github desugars to:

```
filterDbDate2 :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate2 dbes = let extractTime (DbDate time) = [time]
                         extractTime _             = []
                     in concatMap extractTime theDatabase
```

You can rewrite `extractTime` to use `case ... of`:

```
filterDbDate3 :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate3 dbes = let extractTime item = case item of (DbDate time) -> [time]
                                                         _             -> []
                     in concatMap extractTime theDatabase
```

And replace it by a lambda:

```
filterDbDate4 :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate4 dbes = concatMap (\item -> 
    case item of 
        (DbDate time) -> [time]
        _             -> []) 
    theDatabase
```

But imho your original solution using list comprehension looks the best:

```
filterDbDate dbes = [x | (DbDate x) <- dbes]
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Niko has already said in his answer, `filter` cannot change the type. However, there is a variant of `filter` which can: [`Data.Maybe.mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.9/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe). The idea is that if you want to keep an element, then you return `Just newvalue` from the lambda; otherwise you return `Nothing`. In that case, you could rewrite `filterDbDate` as:

```
import Data.Maybe

filterDbDate dbes = mapMaybe (\x -> case x of { DBDate d -> Just d; _ -> Nothing }) dbes
```

Personally, I would say that this is the second-clearest way to write this function (after the list comprehension method).

Answer (score 3):

You were indeed on the right track, as pattern matching is an easy way of solving this, however you will get error as your pattern-matching is not comprehensive. Also, note that if you use filter, you will still get a list of `[DatabaseItem]` as filter never changes the type. You can however use `map` to do it. So:

## Case Of

You can have a `case .. of` inside your lambda function:

```
filterDbDate' :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate' = map (\(DbDate x) -> x) .filter (\x ->
  case x of
    DbDate x -> True
    _        -> False)
```

## Recursion + Pattern Matching

However I think it's more clear using a recursion:

```
filterDbDate'' :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate'' [] = []
filterDbDate'' ((DbDate d):ds) = d : filterDbDate ds
filterDbDate'' (_:ds)          =     filterDbDate ds
```

## Best Way

To be honest, when you have to mix up filter and map, and your lambdas are easy like this one, list comprehensions like yours are the cleanest way:

```
filterDbDate ds = [d | (DbDate d) <- ds]
```

Comment: You could also use `foldr` instead of the recursion